# i need help Rock , paper and scissors exercise

Tags: javascript

i did the "mechanics" but i tried to figured out how to play more rounds, i try a do_while loop but no work so what could be a good practice for more rounds?

```
const arrayPlay = ["rock","paper","scissors"];

const computerPlay = () =>{
    return arrayPlay[~~(Math.random()*arrayPlay.length)]
}
    
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const playRound = (playerSelection,computerSelection) =>{
    if(playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors"){
        console.log("player get's one point");
        playerScore += 1;
    }else if(playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock"){
        console.log("player get's one point");
        playerScore += 1;
    }else if(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper"){
        console.log("player get's one point");
        playerScore += 1;
    }
    if(computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors"){
        console.log("computer get's one point");
        computerScore += 1;
    }else if(computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock"){
        console.log("computer get's one point");
        computerScore += 1;
    }else if(computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper"){
        console.log("computer get's one point");
        computerScore += 1;
    }
}

const playerSelection = prompt("rock,paper or scissors");
const computerSelection = computerPlay();

playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection);
```

Comment: you could set a timeout or you could have a button for play again. or a prompt and call a function to play a round. And why didn't a while loop work?

Comment: Show us your while loop in the code.  After the loop works, you might want to add an `quit` option to the player, so the loop could end.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` constants inside the `playRound` function. Then you can use the `Window.confirm()` method to show the results with a prompt to play again. If they select OK, then just call the `playRound` function again. If they click cancel then the game stops.

See snippet below.

More on `Window.confirm()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

```js
const arrayPlay = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const computerPlay = () => arrayPlay[~~(Math.random() * arrayPlay.length)];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const playRound = () => {
    let playerSelection = prompt(`Please enter either "rock", "paper" or "scissors"`);
    playerSelection = playerSelection ? playerSelection.toLowerCase() : playerSelection;
    if (arrayPlay.includes(playerSelection)) {
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();
        let winner;
        if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
            playerScore += 1;
            winner = `player`;
        } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
            playerScore += 1;
            winner = `player`;
        } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
            playerScore += 1;
            winner = `player`;
        } else if (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors") {
            computerScore += 1;
            winner = `computer`;
        } else if (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock") {
            computerScore += 1;
            winner = `computer`;
        } else if (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper") {
            computerScore += 1;
            winner = `computer`;
        }
        showResults(computerSelection, playerSelection, winner);
    } else if (playerSelection != null){
        if (confirm(`The value you entered: "${playerSelection}" is invalid.\n\nWould you like to try again?`)) {
            playRound();
        }
    }
}

const showResults = (computer, player, winner) => {
    const playAgain = confirm(`
      ---Selection---
      Player:         ${player}
      Computer:  ${computer}
      Results:       ${winner ? `${winner} WINS!!` : "Draw"}
      
      ----Score----
      Player:        ${playerScore}
      Computer:  ${computerScore}
      
      Would you like to play again?`);
    if (playAgain) {
        playRound();
    } else {
        playerScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
    }
}

playRound();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const arrayPlay = ["rock","paper","scissors"];

    const computerPlay = () =>{
        return arrayPlay[~~(Math.random()*arrayPlay.length)]
    }

    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;
    let keepPlaying = true;

// added keep playing condition and a while loop
    while(keepPlaying) {

        const playRound = (playerSelection,computerSelection) =>{
            
// empty input or 'quit' will end the game
            if (playerSelection == "" || playerSelection == "quit") {
                keepPlaying = false;
            }
            else if(playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors"){
                console.log("player get's one point");
                playerScore += 1;
            }else if(playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock"){
                console.log("player get's one point");
                playerScore += 1;
            }else if(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper"){
                console.log("player get's one point");
                playerScore += 1;
            }
            if(computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors"){
                console.log("computer get's one point");
                computerScore += 1;
            }else if(computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock"){
                console.log("computer get's one point");
                computerScore += 1;
            }else if(computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper"){
                console.log("computer get's one point");
                computerScore += 1;
            }
        }

        const playerSelection = prompt("rock,paper or scissors");
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();

        playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection);

// logging the new results
        console.log({playerScore, computerScore})
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const playRound = (playerSelection,computerSelection) =>{
    if(playerSelection == computerSelection) return console.log("tie!")
    //rest of your code here
}

console.log("Type end or stop to finish the game.");

while(true){
  const playerSelection = prompt("rock, paper or scissors");
  if(playerSelection == "end" || playerSelection == "stop"){
    //code to show who won
    break;
  }
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection);
}
```

Next time show code on what you tried, and what part wasn't working.